# Troubleshooting second monitor resolution in 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, xorg, intel-graphics, display-resolution

I am very new to this, so please bear with my utter ignorance if the answer is obvious.

I am trying to troubleshoot a dual monitor setup on a dual boot (Windows 10 + Ubuntu 22.04) machine.

My main monitor is connected via DVI to a discrete NVIDIA card and the secondary monitor is plugged into a mobo via VGA and uses integrated Intel HD 4600. Both monitors support 1080p and the setup has been working flawlessly for a few years using various Windows systems.

However, in Ubuntu the secondary monitor's resolution would not go higher than 1024x768. My understanding is that Intel drivers are built in the kernel so I don't need to update them manually. In my desperation I thought that maybe somehow the xorg Nouveau drivers at fault and installed the recommended Nvidia (515) package instead, to no avail.

xrandr query:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2944 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
VGA-1-1 connected 1024x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96
```

Adding a custom resolution results in an error.

```
me@me-Ubuntu:~$ cvt 1920 1080 60
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
me@me-Ubuntu:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
[sudo] password for me: 
me@me-Ubuntu:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-1-1 "1920x1080_60"
me@me-Ubuntu:~$ sudo xrandr --output  VGA-1-1 --mode 1920x1080_60
xrandr: Configure crtc 4 failed
```

The annoying part is that during my fiddling with this for the past couple of days, **I managed to get it to work once** (through the same xrandr that is refusing to cooperate atm). Alas, being a noob that I am, I haven't saved the profile and all was gone with a reboot. Since then all my attempts to bring the proper resolution back have failed.

During my googling I've encountered suggestions to modify xorg.conf manually but it doesn't exist (xorg.conf.d is empty). And I am not sure what's the proper way to generate it myself, nor what should be the content of the conf file.

BTW, I don't know if that's relevant - in Wayland the second monitor is not even recognised, so I choose xorg as the lesser of two evils.

TIA for any help.